# curl: (35) error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Tags: debian, curl

I am using curl *7.26.0-1+wheezy11* on Debian Wheezy, and whenever I try to access the URL https://www.basebit.com.br, it fails with the message:

```
$ curl https://www.basebit.com.br
curl: (35) error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

I have done some research, and found that `curl --sslv3` should work, but then I get:

```
$ curl --sslv3 https://www.basebit.com.br
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

Some extra information:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.26.0 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP 

$ apt-cache show curl | grep Depends
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libcurl3 (= 7.26.0-1+wheezy11), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)

$ dpkg -l | egrep 'curl|openssl|gnutls'
ii  curl                                     7.26.0-1+wheezy11                    i386         command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax
ii  libcurl3:i386                            7.26.0-1+wheezy11                    i386         easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
ii  libcurl3-gnutls:i386                     7.26.0-1+wheezy11                    i386         easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii  libgnutls26:i386                         2.12.20-8+deb7u2                     i386         GNU TLS library - runtime library
ii  libneon27-gnutls                         0.29.6-3                             i386         HTTP and WebDAV client library (GnuTLS enabled)
ii  openssl                                  1.0.1e-2+deb7u13                     i386         Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
ii  python-openssl                           0.13-2+deb7u1                        i386         Python 2 wrapper around the OpenSSL library

$ ldd $(command -v curl)
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7727000)
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0xb76a7000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb769e000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb7684000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb751f000)
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0xb74ec000)
libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0xb74c2000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0xb74b3000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0xb7460000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xb7422000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xb73c9000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb720b000)
librtmp.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.0 (0xb71f1000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb71d7000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7728000)
libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11 (0xb7152000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb713e000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0xb7122000)
libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26 (0xb7059000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0xb6f86000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xb6f5c000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0xb6f57000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xb6f4e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb6f4a000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0xb6f44000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xb6f3f000)
libtasn1.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3 (0xb6f2d000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0xb6ef0000)
libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5 (0xb6ee6000)
```

I have not been successful in trying to convince the website administrator to [restrict available ciphers in Tomcat’s https connector](http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2012/02/19/tomcat-7-and-curl-ssl23_get_server_hellotlsv1-alert-internal-error/).

Comment: I get the same messages with `curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3` on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to access the URL and found no issue.  I have curl 7.32 installed in Fedora 20.  Could you please provide more details on what is the specific command line you are using (complete command line w/ all parameters, etc) as well as your distribution and the output of "ldd /usr/bin/curl" (or the correct path in case your distribution installs it somewhere else).

Comment: @Marcelo No matter which parameters I give to curl, it fails with that message. All the other requested details have now been included in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have success using the curl options below:

```
curl -vlkL https://www.basebit.com.br --ciphers DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

What HTTP response do you get?